# Blazor not respecting client render mode

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a simple blazor page that has the render mode set to `RenderModeInteractiveWebAssembly` yet as soon as a I add a NavigationManager.NavigateTo function call the injected API service resolves to the registered server `apiService` instance. Removing the Navigation call then results in the correct client side `apiService` instance.

Is this a .net8 bug or am I missing a core concept.

```cs
@page "/people"
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveWebAssembly]
@inject IApiService apiService
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<h3>People</h3>

@if (people == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var person in people)
    {
        <p>@person.Name</p>
    }
}

@code {

    private List<Person> people = new();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var result = await apiService.Get<List<Person>>("/api/people");

        navigationManager.NavigateTo(Routes.Login); // commenting this line, makes the above apiService use the client side instance.
    }
}
```

This is not the final code, as I plan to check the response and if it's unauthorised return the user to the login page. But adding any nagivation changes the behaviour.

I simply register the apiService in both client and server using

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiService, ApiService>();
```

Comment: WASM Prerenders on the server now. This is why you are having to register your services on both Client and server. To prevent this `@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveWebAssembly(prerender: false)]`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: I turned this into an answer for the community.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 8 WASM Prerenders by default on the server now. This is why you are having to register your services on both Client and server.

To prevent this `@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveWebAssembly(prerender: false)]`

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0)